# Terminate calls in Lync 2010

Tags: lync-2010

now I am working with lync 2010 SDK in audio video Modality so,

I want to determine if the call terminated by the user i connect to him or becouse no answer from him

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly what you are asking for, you'd like to know how a conversation terminated.
You can can observe the status changes of the AV modality for each participant.
if you log how the status changed you'll get your answer.
For example you can see if a call ever got connected.

Comment: thanks for reply , and sorry for being late, what i need is to determine the call in decline by user or no answer the user reply normally or the call droped in the middle of it & determine if the answer form the user or from the auto reply user in lync server (leave meassage to the user you try to call) thanks in advance